# Php Regex: Removing parts of url for canonical tag use

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-split

Due to duplicate content issues im trying to create a series of regular expressions to be used in canonical tag (in php).

My header is dynamic and the canonical url is currently set to

```
<link rel="canonical" href="'. BASEHREF . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" />
```

**To demostrate better what im trying to achieve i will give some examples.(the digits are page numbers).**
For example

```
example.com/cars/1,2,etc canonical url points -> example.com (home page)
example.com/car/nissan canonical url points -> example.com (home page)
example.com/new-phones/1,2,3etc  canonical url points -> example.com/new-phones/
```

So essentially when the url contains the words cars,car + digit or word , i want that page canonical url to point to home page, and when the url contains /new-phones/+a number to point on its parent directory.

here is the code i have so far, which is only removing the page number from canonical url.

```
$url = BASEHREF.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$parts = parse_url($url);
$scheme = $parts['scheme'];
$host = $parts['host'];
$path = $parts['path'];

$items = preg_split('/\//',$path,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$thepage = $items[0];
$pagenumber = $items[1];
$canonical_url = ($pagenumber = '') ? $url : $scheme.'://'.$host.'/'.$thepage;
```

Im sure that i must use **if conditions**  but im not good in regex.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This Regex is for `car(s)/number`. [/cars?/\d+](https://regex101.com/r/jD1lZ2/1)

And this one will match your phone. [/new-phones/\d+](https://regex101.com/r/jD1lZ2/2)

You can redirect with php or redirect rules (I would use it personally).

If you want to redirect via redirect rules you need to know under what is your server running.

Since you run under nginx have a look [there](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) but be aware that a redirection rule need to be though. Be sure of what type of redirection you are using (301,etc).

Comment: i run nginx server